# Placing javascripts at the page's bottom and HTTP/2

Tags: javascript, performance, http, load-time

Does the placement of javascripts at the bottom of html document still gives any loadtime wins, if the site runs on HTTP/2?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of putting javascript at the bottom was to make sure the document was loaded before letting javascript interact with the web page. Performance had little if anything to do with it.

HTTP/2 has nothing to do with inlined javascript anyway unless you mean you were placing your loading script at the bottom, meaning `<script src=""></script>`. In that case, you are actually losing performance by not letting the browser jump on downloading the script right away by putting it in the `<head>`.

Comment: as i understand this issue: javascripts block browser at document parsing, if placed in the head. And the question is rather about: HTTP/2 has afaik an ability to priorize ressource download by its own. If javascripts are placed in the head would they still block parsing? - HTTP/2 could eventually priorize them lower and download after the html document, so they no longer block parsing?

Comment: @Evgeniy Downloading javascript will block HTML parsing but you can add the `defer` attribute to `<script>` or dynamically insert the `<script>` but this is all off topic here. See this for more info: https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/prefer-defer-over-async/

Comment: thanks, i know about deferring/async. The question is: whether is it needed if driving HTTP/2?

Comment: Your question was about load time. `defer` doesn't block downloads. H2 has nothing to do with it.